# Frobenius norm minimization with additions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

I am trying to find minimizer X for which

$$ \arg \min_{X} {\left\|| A X + X B - Y \right\||}_{F} $$

when all matrices are square. I know to use the pseudoinverse of A for

$$ \arg \min_{X} {\left\|| A X - Y \right\||}_{F} $$

but don't understand how to rewrite the argument of the first equation to a solvable form.

Comment: Could you tell us what this question is for? For more on this, please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\left\|A X + X B - Y \right\|_F=\|(I\otimes A+B^T\otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(X)-\operatorname{vec}(Y)\|_2$ (see Wikipedia for the meaning of the [$\operatorname{vec}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator), this is just an ordinary least-square problem and a global minimiser is given by $\operatorname{vec}(X)=(I\otimes A+B^T\otimes I)^+\operatorname{vec}(Y)$.